# UIPickerView realtime update on TextField

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uipickerview, textfield

As soon as I scroll the PickerView (or) UIDatePicker, I need the value to get displayed on a TextField :

1. While Scrolling. Even when the picker is moving the text field should update itself. Is it possible ?
2. On the event that the Picker stops moving and comes to rest. Is there an event for the PickerView to come to rest so that I could update the textField (as soon as the pickerView comes to rest).

   ```
     // I do not wish to use the TextFieldDidEndEditing 
    // I want the textField to update itself when the picker view comes to rest.
   ```

It would be helpful if anyone could solve 1) and 2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(1) might not be possible. For (2), you can use the delegate method `pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent`. Let me know if you need any help with this.

**For `UIPickerView`**

(1) Implement `pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent`,

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    // Every time the picker view is rotated, this method will be called to fetch the title.
    NSInteger selectedRow = [pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0];
    // Get selected row like above and process data and update text field.


    [..] // Process the title
    return the title.
}
```

(2) This is more obvious.

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
   // You have the selected row, update the text field.
}
```

Comment: @Deepak, I am bringing the PickerView when textFieldDidBeginEditing.  I want to use [textField setText : (NSString*) ]  as soon as the PickerValue comes to rest .

Comment: You mentioned `UIPickerView`, is it `UIDatePicker`?

Comment: Actually I am using both. Could you help me with UIDatePicker ?

Comment: Both are definitely possible for `UIPickerView` but let me verify whether we can do something about `UIDatePicker`.

Comment: Nope. Even if we got around to tracking the touches, we can't identify the rotation that one gets on swipes. So `UIDatePicker` is not quite possible but `UIPickerView` is.

Comment: You can choose to create a `UIDatePicker` clone using `UIPickerView`.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, this isn't possible with the default control however there is nothing to stop you writing your own and simulate the effect using `touchesMoved` etc...